# Python secrets module acting predictable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked between random and secrets and found that secrets is "cryptographically secure". Everyone stack overflow source says it's the closest to true random. So I thought to use it for generating a population. However, it didn't give very random results at all, rather, predictable results.

The first characteristic I tested was gender, 4 to be exact, and mapped it all out...

```
# code may not function as it's typed on mobile without a computer to test on

import secrets
import multiprocessing


def gen(args*):
    gender = ["Male", "Female", "X", "XXY"]
    rng = secrets.choice(gender)
    return rng

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    id_ = [I for I in range (2000000000)]
    Out = pool.map(gen, id_)
    # Do stuff with the data
```

When I process the data through other functions that determine the percent of 1 gender to the other it is always 25 +- 1% . I was expecting to have the occasional 100% of 1 gender and 0 others, but that never happened.

I also tried the same thing with random, it produced similar results but somehow took twice as long.

I also changed the list gender to have one of X and XXY, while having 49 of the other two, and it gave the predictable result of 1% X and 1% XXY.

I don't have much experience with RNG in computers aside from the term entropy... Does Python have any native or PYPI packages that produce entropy or chaotic numbers?

Is the secrets module supposed to act in a somewhat predictable way?

Comment: The chance of getting 100% of one thing is next to nothing ... each random event is 1/4th if you provide 4 items. Your question makes no sense - just test this for some thousand years and you might get a 100% - one element result...

Comment: So you didn't predict that your results would be predictable...doesn't that make them unpredictable?

Comment: A flat distribution of random numbers is *supposed* to be "predictable" in that way - if each item is equally likely, you expect roughly equal numbers of them. If you repeatedly roll a billion dice, how often do you expect to see all 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be conflating some different ideas here.

The `secrets.choice` function is going to randomly select 1 of the 4 gender options you have provided every time it is called, which in your example is 2000000000 times. The likelihood of getting 100% of any option after randomly selecting from a list of 4 options 2000000000 times is practically zero in any reasonably implemented randomness generator.

If I am understanding your question correctly, this is actually pretty strong evidence that the `secrets.choice` function is behaving as expected and providing an even distribution of the options provided to it. The variance should drop to zero as your N approaches infinity.